# Sort Multi dimensional array by Value and not include to sorting if priority value is 0

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have to sort below given array by Priority. If priority value is 0 then not include in sorting array. I have tried many ways but not getting output as expected.

```
Array
(
[recently_viewed] => Array
    (
        [priority] => 1
        [no_of_products] => 1
    )

[recently_visited_cat] => Array
    (
        [priority] => 1
        [no_of_products] => 1
    )

[last_ordered_items] => Array
    (
        [priority] => 3
        [no_of_products] => 3
    )

[searched_based] => Array
    (
        [priority] => 0
        [no_of_products] => 4
    )

[cart_based] => Array
    (
        [priority] => 1
        [no_of_products] => 5
    )

[wishlist_based] => Array
    (
        [priority] => 1
        [no_of_products] => 6
    )

[sku_based] => Array
    (
        [priority] => 0
        [no_of_products] => 7
    )
)
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: I have also tried it but not working. so posted new question.

Comment: Then please share your attempts so we can help with that.

Comment: I guess you should use `array_filter` for priority 0 before sorting

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to exclude records with 0 priority. After it you can sort the array with help [`uasort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function. For example:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($element) {
    return $element['priority'] > 0;
});

uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['priority'] === $b['priority']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['priority'] < $b['priority']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Your `uasort` callback code can simply be `return $a['priority'] <=> $b['priority']` or `return $a['priority'] - $b['priority']` (pre PHP7). Note that it also depends if a higher priority has a higher or lower priority value (otherwise just switch operands).

Comment: @Jeto of course, but I don't know what PHP version use author, therefore I don't use <=> operator

Comment: Right--the other alternative (with `-`) works on any version though.

Answer (score 1):

You can us `array_filter` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - for check bigger then 0) and then `uasort` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)):

```
$arr = [];
$arr["recently_viewed"] = ["priority" => 1, "no_of_products" =>1];
$arr["searched_based"] = ["priority" => 0, "no_of_products" =>4];
$arr["last_ordered_items"] = ["priority" => 3, "no_of_products" =>3];

$arr = array_filter($arr, function ($e) {return $e["priority"];});
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['priority'] - $b['priority'];
});
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/E5bNa)

Comment: If priority is 1 then it should be in first in array.

Comment: @Magecode - I make desc order - update the order of the `$a` and `$b` - now it is asc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` with `callback` function to remove the values with `ZERO`

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function ($e) {return $e["priority"];});
```

This will remove all the sub-array which has priority values ZERO.

Now you can apply `usort` to sort the array

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b)  {
    return $a['priority'] <=> $b['priority'];
});
```

See Working Code [Live](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/890b65471b48238ae3a82ab9b811a1b64c096591)

Comment: First notice the keys of the array - OP probably want to keep them - so use `uasort` and not `usort`. Second - what is different here then other answer?